# PropertyPage - Take control from Ok button

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am creating a Property Page. On the page, I have a Button named Add. I want the user to be able to hit enter and then the Add button is clicked and not the Ok button. Is this possible to do?

One option I have thought about is to add code in the performOk() method to check what needs to happen. But I don't like this approach unless it is the only way.

```
@Override
public boolean performOk(){
    //Do stuff
    //Ok hit. Should Add have been hit.
}
```

Comment: Just added my thoughts.. are they clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button used when Enter is pressed is the Shell 'default' button.

In a property page you could set it with:

```
getShell().setDefaultButton(buton);
```

You would have to make sure the default is reset whenever your property page becomes inactive.

I think changing the default away from the OK button might be very confusing.